ROS2 equivalent for roslaunch_add_file_check?
I am new to ROS2 and trying to port some ROS1 code over to ROS2. In the ROS1 packages that I have written in the past, we used the roslaunch_add_file_check macro in CMakelists to ensure there were no errors in the launch file.
Is there an equivalent for this in ROS2?
This was very useful for us in the past as our continuous integration server would catch any issues with launch files using roslaunch_add_file_check. If equivalent functionality is available in ROS2, I would appreciate pointers to them. Thanks.
